Removing Air from Hot Water Cast Iron Baseboard
see https://legendvalve.com/documents/iom/t-569%20and%20t-570%20tees%20iom.pdf top diagram on page 2 shows my configuration.
I have Hot water baseboard, circulator system configured as a loop with radiators off the main feed (standard tee into heater, venturi tee out ).  One of the radiators is not heating up. All the others in the loop work fine.  I am able to bleed the system through the bleeder to the right of the heating element in the picture (and the radiator gets hot, but cools down when I close the bleeder valve). I think there must be air trapped between the bleeder and the venturi (t-569 in picture, about 10' of distance).  How can I remove this air, or what else might be wrong.  One thought is to install a cutoff valve on the main feed just after the standard tee to force the water through the radiator and clear the air.
Note this system is about 60 years old (radiators and radiator plumbing, remainder about 23 years old) and worked fine before a lot of air was introduced into the system.  It has been purged of air except for this problem.

They sell Automatic air vent for radiators.
Find the one that fits your radiator and let it work,
source air vent
Eventually it will release all the trapped air
Install another one in the pipes close to the pump
